# How to group & order by distinct labels with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Just started off with neo4j and thought that I'll use a real life model to teach myself. Getting stuck with the following

#### Model

`(d:Destination)-[:Hosts]->(a:Accommodation)`

`:Accommodation is sub-typed with other labels as :Homestay / :Hotel / :Guesthouse etc.`

#### Query

For a given `d.name`, would like to retrieve all `a.names` grouped by their sub-types

Will appreciate help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To layer on Martin Preusse's solution, you could filter out the *Accomodation* label in an interim step and return the zeroth element.  This assumes that there are at least two labels to start with of course (i.e. that there is a sub classification indeed present).

```
match (d:Destination)-[:HOSTS]->(a:Accomodation)
with d
, a
, filter(type in labels(a) where type <> 'Accomodation')[0] as type
return d.name, type, collect(a.name)
```

Comment: Thanks Dave
I've also noticed that LABELS(a) could be treated as an array. If it is guaranteed that labels are always ordered as :supertype:subtype, then the query can simply group the subtypes as LABELS(a)[1]
So this also works:
`MATCH (d:Destination)-[:Hosts]-(a:Accommodation)
WHERE d.name = 'some name'
RETURN DISTINCT labels(a)[1], collect(a.name)`

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen anywhere that a specific order was guaranteed for labels.  I think in older versions the label collection was ordered by the order that you added them to a node. In 2.3 it appears that they come out alphabetically though. However, there is no label hierarchy defined anywhere so ordering by hierarchy would have to be inferred.  **I definitely would not rely on that.** If you do know that your nodes will have a specific number of labels though you can parse the ones out of the collection that you don't want.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
MATCH (d:Destination)-[:Hosts]-(a:Accomodation)
WHERE d.name = 'some name'
RETURN DISTINCT labels(a), collect(a.name)
```

If you want to query the subtypes, it might be easier to put them in a node property.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. May be too little knowledge is becoming dangerous at my end :) but I remember reading somewhere - querying on labels is faster than querying on a node.property. Hence, used the sub-types

Comment: The advantage is that you can e.g. return only the sub-type of an `Accomodation`. Depends on your queries, just a suggestion.